# How to set HSV color range in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, hsv, hsb

I have a phone and it's HSV histogram like blow,and I want to track this phone's movement.Based on it's histogram,I set image range like this:

```
greenLower = (300, 0, 50)
greenUpper = (50, 128,250 )
cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
```

But nothing got detected out when waving the phone,and I am pretty sure it is because color range is wrong,would you tell me how to get color rang setting right？Especially,when HUE values are between [300~50],should I set it to (50~300) or (300~50) due to HUE is a cirle.

```
Phone
```

[image: Phone]

```
HSV histogram:
```

[image: HSV Histogram]

Comment: How did you obtain the HSV? Seems a bit odd that only saturation is floating point between 0.0 and 1.0. | The question about `inRange` gets answered by reading the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrongly set the upper and lower bounds, they must be:

```
greenLower = (50, 0, 50)         # Previously (300, 0, 50)
greenUpper = (300, 128, 250)     # Previously (50, 128,250)
```

Also make sure that `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)` as OpenCV follows the `BGR` convention.

**EDIT:**

To segment colors in multiple ranges `0~50` and `300~359`, you can perform `cv2.inRange()` twice for two ranges as:

```
greenLower1 = (0, 0, 20)         
greenUpper1 = (50, 128, 100)     

greenLower2 = (300, 0, 20)         
greenUpper2 = (359, 128, 100)     

mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, greenLower1, greenUpper1)
mask2 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, greenLower2, greenUpper2)

mask = cv2.max(mask1, mask2)
```

Comment: Still,nothing got detected out,will you suggestion match the hue value in a single range 50~300 or two ranges  0~50 and 300~359

Comment: It will work in range `50~300` and was working fine on my machine with your input image, Have you converted the input image to HSV properly?

Comment: @ZdarR，thanks,I have converted image to HSV as you suggested,and according to histogram,the really ranges should be  0~50 and 300~359,and I just don't kown how to combine these two as single one

Comment: Updated @AlexLuya, But I guess there is some error in your calculations, as the output is still same because `300~359` is not showing any effect. Also your Intensity ranges from `0-255`, but in case of HSV the intensity ranges from `0-100`